# Conky: Is there a way to have multiple-line blocks of text aligned horizontally?

Tags: conky

I have been using a sligtly optimized version of Andeon's [conky-simple](https://github.com/andeon/conky-simple), as shown below.

[image]

Unfortunately, I do not have much experience with conky scripts, so I am not sure I can actually do what I have in mind: I would like to have each of these sections (System, CPU Usage, etc) aligned horizontally, as "paragraphs" or blocks lined at the top of the screen, with a small padding space between. I would like each block to mantain its current appearance, but lined side by side instead of stacked.

Is there any way to do that on Conky? I have read a few articles regarding offsets and so on, but did not get many results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for something straightforward like a table-type structure, the answer is no. But it should be possible to get the appearance you're looking for.

To solve the problem directly in a single conky script, you'd have to deal with each line separately. That is, it would be necessary to combine the first line of each block horizontally, then the second line, then the third, and so on. It could be done, but it'd be tedious and the script would be very messy.

In a single conky script, you could also try setting `minimum_width` to your desired horizontal width and then placing `${offset x}${voffset -y}` before the first line of a block and `${offset x}` before each subsequent block line that needs to be repositioned so as to position them where you want (where `x` and `-y` are numbers of pixels for each offset). For example, see the conky file available for free at https://store.kde.org/p/1112169/. However, this would take tedious trial-and-error to get everything right. Also, any later change before repositioned lines would most likely through off the positioning of those lines since the offsets are relative to where the lines initially fall in the display.

If you're willing to run multiple instances of conky, it should be fairly easy to separate the blocks into separate conky script files, include appropriate positioning commands in each, and run each in a separate conky instance.

It might also be possible by writing a Lua script, but it wouldn't be trivial. Basically, the Lua script would retrieve the needed data and construct the lines that would otherwise need to be created manually as discussed above. The `conky_parse` function (referred to in conky's `man` file) would need to be used in the Lua script to retrieve each of the various values to be displayed. If you're interested in delving into it and you're not familiar with Lua, check out [the Lua reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/).

None of these approaches is terribly palatable, but it seems they're the only ones that are possible.